# How to cross-compile ROS for BeagleBoard-xM (ARM)

Tags: ros, beagleboard, cross-compilation, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to cross-compile ROS stacks for a BeagleBoard-xM. How should I proceed? I haven't got any experience with cross-compilation. I've read there is a stack for this purpose called [eros](http://www.ros.org/wiki/eros), is it still alive? Or is it better to go with OpenEmbedded or CodeSourcery, or is rostoolchain.cmake enough?

I've already managed to build all the stacks necessary by compiling them directly on the BB-xM once (Ubuntu 10.10), but this takes a lot of time and is prone to errors (see [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/154/minimizing-compiler-memory-pcl_ros) or [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/146/how-to-add-additional-compile-flags)). So I'd like to learn how to cross-compile to avoid such problems in the future.

Any hints appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9232/how-to-cross-compile-ros-for-beagleboard-xm-(arm)/) by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1079 on 2011-02-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In answer to your question, I think you need to understand the roles of each

- OpenEmbedded : its a system builder, as you already have ubuntu installed, you dont need it. It can build you toolchains, but there are probably easier ways to get a toolchain if you already have ubuntu installed.
- CodeSourcery : it's a toolchain (cross compiler + utilities). I haven't actually had any problems with these, and eros even has a [package](http://www.ros.org/wiki/code_sourcery_arm_gnueabi) which helps you install a code sourcery g++/glibc toolchain on 32 bit systems.
- Eros is not a system builder, nor a toolchain. It simply brings all the elements together so that you can cross-compile ros easily.

As for the situation you have described, you don't need to worry about a system builder. The next step is a toolchain, code sourcery should be ok, though I also see [maverick](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=arm-linux&searchon=names&suite=maverick&section=all) now includes arm-linux toolchains. These latter toolchains will probably be a better fit (no chance of libc/libc++ mismatches) but I haven't tested them myself.

Once you have a toolchain, you can use eros to help you do a [toolchain bridge](http://www.ros.org/wiki/eros/Tutorials/Toolchain%20Bridge) (i.e. install the apache runtimes, log4cxx and boost into your toolchain) and globally configure the ros environment for cross compiling.

This will work well for simple systems, but if you're using large stacks of packages with alot of other rosdeps, then it probably isn't viable as you haven't got a good means of installing those rosdeps into your toolchain. Eros could add build scripts for some of these, though I'd like to see eros fill this need by using something like openembedded under the hood to do so. If you have an ubuntu already installed, a simple hack that might work is to copy libs and headers for rosdeps from your board across into your toolchain.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2011-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can find the explanation of Markus Klotzbuecher for our students embedded control systems here: [http://people.mech.kuleuven.be/~mklotzbucher/ecs-assignments/ecs.html#sec-6_1](http://people.mech.kuleuven.be/%7Emklotzbucher/ecs-assignments/ecs.html#sec-6_1) this is based on the standard gcc arguments.

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-02-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2011-03-01**:
Thanks Koen, very nice introductory materials.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is how I managed to cross-compile `groovy` for the `beagleboard-XM` running `debian-armhf/stable`.

It requires that you already have a groovy functional version on the host and a corresponding catkin_workspace containing the sources.
it is of course not the only way to proceed, but it worked for me.
it is tested under the following environment:

```
host system: debian-amd64/wheezy. groovy installed in /opt/ros/groovy 
target system: debian-armhf/wheezy. groovy will be installed in /opt/ros/beagleboard
```

on the host system,
the cross-compiler must be installed.
edit and update the `sources.list` to add the `emdebian` repository

```
deb http://www.emdebian.org/debian/ unstable main
```

install gcc for armhf

```
sudo apt-get install g++-4.7-arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

groovy must be prepared to be cross-compiled.
create a copy of the groovy workspace for armhf.
(customize the path if required)

```
cp -rv ~/robot/ros/catkin_workspace_amd64 ~/robot/ros/catkin_workspace_armhf
```

create the configuration file configuration `ros_armhf_toolchain.cmake` from `rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake`

```
cd ~/robot/ros/catkin_workspace_armhf
cp -v ./src/rosbuild/core/rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake ./src/rosbuild/core/rosbuild/ros_armhf_toolchain.cmake
```

edit the file to update the following variables

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.7)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++-4.7)
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX /opt/ros/beagleboard)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM BOTH)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY) 
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf) # armhf dependencies install dir
set(CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING OFF) # enable if required
```

install the missing libraries
(you may work in a `chroot` if you prefer)

```
sudo xapt --keep-cache -a armhf -m libboost-system-dev libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-program-options-dev libpython2.7 python2.7-dev  libboost-signals-dev libboost-regex-dev libboost-date-time-dev libboost-thread-dev liblog4cxx10-dev libtinyxml-dev libbz2-dev libeigen3-dev libtiff-dev libassimp-dev libpoco-dev
```

There's perhaps a cleaner way to perform this step, but I did not find it.
Copy the environment files from groovy

```
mkdir -p /opt/ros/beagleboard
cd /opt/ros/groovy
cp -v env.sh   setup.bash  setup.sh  _setup_util.py  setup.zsh /opt/ros/beagleboard
```

edit setup.sh to replace /opt/ros/groovy with /opt/ros/beagleboard

```
cd /opt/ros/beagleboard
```

launch a first compilation
(you may of course add other packages)

```
source setup.bash
cd ~/robot/ros/catkin_workspace_armhf
./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --pkg  roslib roscpp  rostime rosconsole roscpp_serialization xmlrpcpp message_filters tf actionlib_msgs actionlib catkin rosbash roslaunch rosparam  rosservice  rostest  rostopic  topic_tools rosmsg rosbag genpy rospkg genmsg rosclean rosgraph_msgs rosmaster rosout rosgraph std_msgs --install --install-space /opt/ros/beagleboard   -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=~/robot/ros/catkin_workspace_armhf/src/rosbuild/core/rosbuild/ros_armhf_toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=true \
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
```

at this step, this first compilation ended because of linker errors.
Edit the following files to replace groovy with beagleboard
(you may also use awk for that)

```
cd ~/robot/ros/catkin_workspace_armhf
vi build_isolated/rosconsole/CMakeFiles/rosconsole.dir/link.txt
vi build_isolated/roscpp/CMakeFiles/roscpp.dir/link.txt
vi build_isolated/tf/CMakeFiles/tf.dir/link.txt
vi build_isolated/tf/CMakeFiles/pytf_py.dir/link.txt
vi build_isolated/tf/CMakeFiles/static_transform_publisher.dir/link.txt
vi build_isolated/tf/CMakeFiles/testBroadcaster.dir/link.txt
vi build_isolated/tf/CMakeFiles/tf_change_notifier.dir/link.txt
vi build_isolated/tf/CMakeFiles/tf_echo.dir/link.txt
vi build_isolated/tf/CMakeFiles/tf_empty_listener.dir/link.txt
vi build_isolated/tf/CMakeFiles/tf_monitor.dir/link.txt
```

the following packages could not be properly installed
they have to be manually installed
repeat this step with the other packages

```
cd src/cpp_common
mkdir build;cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=~/robot/ros/catkin_workspace_armhf/src/rosbuild/core/rosbuild/ros_armhf_toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/beagleboard -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=true -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON ..
make install
cd ..
```

start a second compilation

```
cd ~/robot/ros/catkin_workspace_armhf
./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --pkg  roslib roscpp  rostime rosconsole roscpp_serialization xmlrpcpp message_filters tf actionlib_msgs actionlib catkin rosbash roslaunch rosparam  rosservice  rostest  rostopic  topic_tools rosmsg rosbag genpy rospkg genmsg rosclean rosgraph_msgs rosmaster rosout rosgraph std_msgs --install --install-space /opt/ros/beagleboard   -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=~/robot/ros/catkin_workspace_armhf/src/rosbuild/core/rosbuild/ros_armhf_toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=true \
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
```

At this step, the tree `/opt/ros/beagleboard` is ready to be transfered to the board

On the board, install the missing packages
alternative: you may get the packages created by `xapt` in `/var/lib/xapt/output`, to copy them to the board
and install the required deb files via `dpkg`

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-system1.49.0 libboost-filesystem1.49.0 libboost-program-options1.49.0 libboost-signals1.49.0 \
libboost-regex1.49.0 libboost-date-time1.49.0 libboost-thread1.49.0 liblog4cxx10 libpython2.7 python2.7 libtinyxml2.6.2 bzip2 libtiff4 libassimp3 libpococrypto9 libpocodata9 libpocofoundation9 libpocomysql9 \
libpoconet9 libpoconetssl9 libpocoodbc9 libpocosqlite9 libpocoutil9 libpocoxml9 libpocozip9 \
python-netifaces python-yaml python-catkin-pkg python-empy python-nose
```

transfer the tree `/opt/ros/beagleboard` from the PC to the board
if required, update your /etc/hosts to add the PC host address

```
192.168.1.7       debian-pc
```

Update $HOME/.bashrc to add the following lines
(customize if necessary)

```
source /opt/ros/beagleboard/setup.bash
export ROS_IP=<beagleboard_ip>
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://debian-pc:11311
```

you may now try the beginner_tutorials

```
source $HOME/.bashrc
```

install talker on the PC and listener on the board for instance

---

Originally posted by [Fabien R](https://answers.ros.org/users/2975/fabien-r/) with karma: 90 on 2013-11-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1